# SQL Server pass variable instead of hard coding root element name

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2008, I have is query

```
DECLARE @root AS varchar(20);
SET @root = 'Root';

DECLARE @element AS varchar(20);
SET @element = 'Element';

SELECT
    *
FROM 
    SomeTable
FOR XML PATH (@element), ROOT(@root);
```

What I want is to pass a variables instead of hard coding the name of the repeating element and the root.

When I execute the query, it throws this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '@element'.
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try dynamic SQL -

```
DECLARE 
  @Root VARCHAR(20)
, @Element VARCHAR(20)
, @SQL NVARCHAR(500)

SELECT 
  @Root = 'Root'
, @Element = 'Element'
, @SQL = N'
 SELECT *
 FROM Labour.Absence a
 FOR XML PATH (''' + @Element + '''), ROOT(''' + @Root + ''')' 

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Unfortunately t-sql syntax does not allow specifying variables inside this construction. So dymanic SQL is the only way for this situation.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth learning to read the documentation for SQL Server. If you look at the [`FOR` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173812.aspx) you'll see:

```
| PATH [ ( 'ElementName' ) ] 
...
[ , ROOT [ ( 'RootName' ) ] ]
```

If you compare this with other documentation, here I'll use as an example [`BACKUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx):

```
 { 'physical_device_name' | @physical_device_name_var }
...
FILE = { logical_file_name | @logical_file_name_var } 
| FILEGROUP = { logical_filegroup_name | @logical_filegroup_name_var }
```

That is, when it's valid to pass only a string, they'll only show a `''` delimited value in the syntax diagram. When it's possible to pass a *variable*, they'll explicitly show it as an option (with a `@` name). And when you have to provide a *name* rather than a *string*, they'll show it without `''` marks

So, as @Devart says, the only possibility is to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I don't care for this answer. I shouldn't need documentation for my documentation.

Comment: @Tony - most e.g. textbooks will have a section towards the start labelled "how to read this documentation" that discusses the typographical conventions used throughout the rest of the book. Of course, most of the time it's safe to skip it and you'll be able to work it out. I wrote this answer because I couldn't (at the time) find a similar section to BOL, but that's what's really needed here - you need to understand the typographical conventions of any documentation to fully understand it.

Comment: @Damen_The_Unbeliever I understand the necessity and importance of understanding documentation syntax, but you seemed to make a magic leap from one example to another. I came to this question because I wanted to be able to include a datetime stamp in the ROOT variable.  I wouldn't have guessed it wasn't allowed.  Even concats are disallowed; ie, ROOT('Hi '+'there')